# Booting time too long and repatedly freezes the system

Tags: boot, 16.04, launcher, freeze, netbeans

I installed or upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm having some problems with working on Netbeans IDE(PHP), the whole system freezes repeatedly .Does the issue related to netbeans or 16.04

```
`dmesg` results some errors like







[ 1469.495610] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 15837560
[ 1469.495618] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979488, lost async page write
[ 1469.495630] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979489, lost async page write
[ 1469.495635] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979490, lost async page write
[ 1469.495640] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979491, lost async page write
[ 1469.495645] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979492, lost async page write
[ 1469.495651] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979493, lost async page write
[ 1469.495656] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979494, lost async page write
[ 1469.495662] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979495, lost async page write
[ 1469.495667] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979496, lost async page write
[ 1469.495671] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1979497, lost async page write
[ 1469.497310] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1469.497318] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f1 aa 68 00 00 f0 00
[ 1469.497322] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 15837800
[ 1469.504960] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1469.505032] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

And  `systemd-analyze blame` giving output

```
 7.337s dev-sda6.device
      6.274s ModemManager.service
      5.634s snapd.refresh.service
      5.414s apparmor.service
      4.967s accounts-daemon.service
      4.744s apport.service
      4.214s networking.service
      3.897s systemd-logind.service
      3.895s speech-dispatcher.service
      3.735s thermald.service
      3.700s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.671s systemd-user-sessions.service
      3.670s pppd-dns.service
      3.293s avahi-daemon.service
      2.966s NetworkManager.service
      2.703s console-setup.service
      2.324s gpu-manager.service
      2.143s grub-common.service
      1.839s systemd-udevd.service
      1.192s dns-clean.service
      1.131s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.129s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
      1.127s plymouth-start.service
      1.125s rsyslog.service
      1.073s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.050s keyboard-setup.service
      1.047s polkitd.service
       874ms systemd-journald.service
       823ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       822ms irqbalance.service
       820ms lightdm.service
       737ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       718ms ondemand.service
       681ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       593ms udisks2.service
       587ms apt-daily.service
       569ms systemd-hostnamed.service
       538ms resolvconf.service
       530ms upower.service
       464ms dev-hugepages.mount
       426ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       411ms kmod-static-nodes.service
```

then execute command fdisk -ls

```
    Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3ffc3ff

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       206848 102402047 102195200  48.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102402048 335874047 233472000 111.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       335874048 581634047 245760000 117.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       581636094 625141759  43505666  20.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       581636096 583634943   1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       583636992 625141759  41504768  19.8G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Can you please suggest any solution

Comment: Your disk is on the way out?

Comment: Any solution?@Jacek

Comment: How is your sdc disk connected to the system? Cheers, Al

Comment: Well - if your disk is dying the solution is to replace it. Anyway - it may be a good idea to check drive's condition with smartctl.